# Invalid parameter error on SetLayeredWindowAttributes

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, pinvoke

For ease of debugging I added a console window to my WPF application in which I can monitor all ongoing events in the application. I also added some nice methods which automatically move the window to my secondary screen, maximizes it and sets it's opacity to 90%.

Using the debug configuration it work's absolutely fine and as expected. But as soon as I use the release configuration I catch some weird exceptions. Using this P/Invoke implementation:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);

public static void SetOpacity(byte alpha)
{
    IntPtr handle = GetConsoleWindow();
    if (handle == IntPtr.Zero) return;

    Logging.Trace("Found console handle.");
    Logging.Trace($"Setting console opacity to: {alpha}.");

    if (!SetLayeredWindowAttributes(handle, 0, alpha, 0x2))
    {
        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        Logging.Trace($"Return value: {error}");
        if (error != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(error);
    }

    Logging.Trace("Set LW attributes.");
}
```

Running this without the logging I get back "**87**: The parameter is incorrect". When I add the logging I get (weird as it is) "**183**: Cannot create a file when that file already exists."

I really don't understand why this happens. And why logging influences the outcome. And why this works using debug configuration.

Comment: btw GetLastWin32Error is *only* valid/meaningful if SetLayeredWindowAttributes fails (returns 0)

Comment: The error has nothing to do with SetLayeredWindowAttributes. You did not check the return value of that function. GetLastError is only meaningful if a) the function returns FALSE, and b) you call GetLastError **immediately after the call to SetLayeredWindowAttributes fails**. You have no idea whether it failed or not, because you do not check the value, and you do not call GetLastError immediately in any case; you have a call to your logging before you call GetLastError. Learn to **properly** check API call results and use GetLastError.

Comment: Okay sorry, that was obvious. I admit that. But moving it to be called instantly afterwards it still returns **87** and fails in release configuration. Why does it work in in Debug configuration? And doesn't a return value of 0 mean "success"?

Comment: @SharpShade, *And doesn't a return value of 0 mean "success"?*  Check the MSDN documentation, please... ;)

Comment: For Windows API calls, return values of 0 only mean success in functions that return `HRESULT`s, because 0 is `S_OK`. Functions that don't return `HRESULT`s return traditional C boolean values instead, so nonzero would mean success (hence `if (!Call(...)) panic()`).

Comment: Okay I meant the error codes, of course 0 is "failed" when it comes to the return value. And sorry, I'm relatively new to P/Invoke so forgive me, please. But nonetheless I don't understand why changing the build configuration breaks this code. I changed the code and it still throws the exception for no clear reason...

Comment: Are you sure the exception you get from running in Release mode is the one you threw, and not something else?

Comment: This code is being executed as the very first in my application's constructor. Thus there's not much around (other thread or anything) which could intercept. The console output clearly nails it down to this method and exactly to that throw-expression. I don't see any other way. But I found some clues which require a lot more work (currently working on the implementation) which might resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` only works on windows that have the `WS_EX_LAYERED` attribute.  Chances are that the console window does not have that style, which would explain the error 87 you are seeing.  So you will have to set the style with `SetWindowLongPtr()` beforehand, eg:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="GetWindowLong", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="GetWindowLongPtr", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="SetWindowLong", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="SetWindowLongPtr", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags); 

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void SetLastError(uint dwErrorCode);

private static IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex)
{
    if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        return GetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex);
    else
        return GetWindowLongPtr32(hWnd, nIndex);
}

private static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong)
{
    if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
    else
        return SetWindowLongPtr32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
}

private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
private const int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000;

public static void SetOpacity(byte alpha)
{
    if (alpha == byte.MaxValue)
    {
        MakeOpaque();
        return;
    }

    IntPtr handle = GetConsoleWindow();
    if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        return;

    Logging.Trace("Found console handle.");

    int error;

    SetLastError(0);
    int winFlags = (int) GetWindowLongPtr(handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    if (winFlags == 0)
    {
        error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (error != 0)
        {
            Logging.Trace($"GetWindowLongPtr error: {error}");
            throw new Win32Exception(error);
        }
    }

    if ((winFlags & WS_EX_LAYERED) == 0)
    {
        Logging.Trace($"Setting console layered style.");

        winFlags |= WS_EX_LAYERED;
        SetLastError(0);
        if (SetWindowLongPtr(handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, new IntPtr(winFlags)) == 0)
        {
            error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (error != 0)
            {
                Logging.Trace($"SetWindowLongPtr error: {error}");
                throw new Win32Exception(error);
            }
        }
    }

    Logging.Trace($"Setting console opacity to: {alpha}."); 

    if (!SetLayeredWindowAttributes(handle, 0, alpha, 0x2))
    {
        error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        Logging.Trace($"SetLayeredWindowAttributes error: {error}");
        throw new Win32Exception(error);
    }

    Logging.Trace("Set LW attributes.");
}
```

Comment: I can't use `IntPtr winFlags & WS_EX_LAYERED`or anything similiar. IntPtr does not have any of these operators nor does it have implicit int/long conversion. Guess I go with casting to `long` PS: Running .Net 4.6.1 if this has been changed somehow or been added later on.

Comment: I fixed the arithmetic in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But shouldn't you use `long`? After all long can be used in 32-bit applications as well but casting a 8 byte `IntPtr` into `int` would cause an exception.

Comment: @SharpShade per the `IntPtr` documentation: "*An exception is only thrown if the value of `value` requires more bits than the current platform supports*". That is not the case with window styles, which fit in 32 bits (otherwise 32bit apps couldn't use them), so casting the return value of `GWL_EXSTYLE` to `int` is safe.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research I found out that there is more to the [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540(v=vs.85).aspx) method. I can't explain why this does work perfectly fine when building in debug configuration but to make it work with release configuration you need to first enhance the window style with [SetWindowLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591(v=vs.85).aspx) (you will also need [GetWindowLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585(v=vs.85).aspx)). *Note that you should use the methods with suffix 'Ptr' since only those work on x86 and x64 Windows versions*.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
private static extern int SetWindowLongPtr(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr")]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLongPtr")]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
private const int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000;

public static void SetOpacity(byte alpha)
{
    if (alpha == byte.MaxValue)
    {
        MakeOpaque();
        return;
    }

    IntPtr handle = GetConsoleWindow();
    if (handle == IntPtr.Zero) return;

    int error;

    if (IntPtr.Size == 4) // x86
    {
        int winFlags = GetWindowLongPtr32(handle, GWL_EXSTYLE).ToInt32();
        winFlags |= WS_EX_LAYERED;
        if (SetWindowLongPtr(new HandleRef(Core.IDE, handle), GWL_EXSTYLE, winFlags) == 0)
        {
            error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Win32Exception(error);
        }
    }
    else // x64
    {
        long winFlags = GetWindowLongPtr64(handle, GWL_EXSTYLE).ToInt64();
        winFlags |= WS_EX_LAYERED;
        if (SetWindowLongPtr64(new HandleRef(Core.IDE, handle), GWL_EXSTYLE, new IntPtr(winFlags)).ToInt64() == 0)
        {
            error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Win32Exception(error);
        }
    }

    if (!SetLayeredWindowAttributes(handle, 0, alpha, 0x2))
    {
        error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        Logging.Trace($"Return value: {error}");
        if (error != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(error);
    }
}
```

With this everything works perfectly fine on both architectures. The code in short you can find here on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632598(v=vs.85).aspx#layered_win) which you should be able to easily convert to C#.

Comment: You don't need to divide your code into 32bit and 64bit branches like this. `(Get|Set)WindowLongPtr` operate on `LONG_PTR` which is 4 bytes in 32bit and 8 bytes in 64bit. Write your code to use `(Get|Set)WindowLongPtr` and `LONG_PTR` *correctly* and your code will be much simpler as the `if/else` can be removed

Comment: Yeah I've seen that in the samples on pinvoke.net, but when I implemented it I got errors when trying to use operators on IntPtr. Maybe there was an unfinished if or something else which confused the IDE a bit there. Thanks for the addition!