# winxpgui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes throwing error pywintypes.error: (87, 'SetLayeredWindowAttributes', 'The parameter is incorrect.')

Tags: python, pywinauto, win32gui, win32con

While I am trying to make a window's background transparent using win32gui, I am using following code.

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "My App Name")
win32gui.SetWindowLong (hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, win32gui.GetWindowLong (hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE ) | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED )
winxpgui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(0,0,0), 180, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)
```

But I am getting an error as

```
pywintypes.error: (87, 'SetLayeredWindowAttributes', 'The parameter is incorrect.')
```

I tried different documentation, but could not really find anything very specific or helpful. Would anyone like to give some suggestion or code snippet or idea to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check `if hwnd is not None`. At this answer such code works: [Make a window transparent using Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4549213/3648361) All other parameters are constants. Maybe you need `FindWindowEx` instead of `FindWindow`. `Ex` version works across process boundaries, while `FindWindow` is for this process only.

EDIT1:
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44276373/3648361
It tells that `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` only works on windows that have the `WS_EX_LAYERED` attribute. But fortunately it can be set by `SetWindowLongPtr()`.

Comment: hwnd is not None. I used that example only while I am getting the error.
This is working for notepad, but getting error for another app - not sure if it does not work for all apps.

Comment: Maybe it's some handling error on the app side? Does it support setting such attribute?

Comment: How do I know if it supports such attribute? You mean to say not all windows app can be made transparent?

Comment: Yes, "`SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` only works on windows that have the `WS_EX_LAYERED` attribute." See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44276373/3648361 But this general attribute can be set. If it helps, I'd suggest to +1 this pretty old answer. I've just found it, but you asked the right question!

Comment: I tried calling `win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED)` before SetLayeredWindowAttributes,  but no luck

Comment: It looks like necessary function is absent in `win32gui` module. You have to try `ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW` with defining its signature first. Please read the docs about `ctypes` and docs for the function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw